# Цикл и проверка

Tags: php

Есть цикл, мне нужно, что бы каждые 2 элемента которые он выводит оборачивались в отдельный блок. допустим с классом row. Помогите плиз

```html
<?php foreach($locations as $location): ?>

<div data-code="<?php echo $location['code'] ?>" class="location-country dropdown-toggle<?php echo $location['is_active'] ? '' : ' non-active' ?>">
  <div class="lock-l">
    <div class="img-loc"><img id="img-country" src="/img/<?php echo $location['code']; ?>.png" alt="img"></div>
    <div class="namr-loc">
      <?php echo $location['name']; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: А причём тут метка **javascript**? Какие элементы?

Comment: А как по другому написать проверку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

перед форичем попробуйте [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php) при помощи этой функции вы можете разу разбить весь массив по 2 элемента.

Увы не совсем понял почему нужно это проверять на js, если можно сразу вывести так как требуется. Или все таки условие именно разбить по 2 элемента уже на js?

```
<?php $chunkedLocations = array_chunk($locations, 2, true); ?>

<div class="locationsHolder">


  <?php foreach($chunkedLocations as $row): ?>
  <div class="row">

    <?php foreach($row as $location): ?>

    <div data-code="<?php echo $location['code'] ?>" class="location-country dropdown-toggle<?php echo $location['is_active'] ? '' : ' non-active' ?>">
      <div class="lock-l">
        <div class="img-loc"><img id="img-country" src="/img/<?php echo $location['code']; ?>.png" alt="img"></div>
        <div class="namr-loc">
          <?php echo $location['name']; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

  </div>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Условия такого нету, просто, я думал, что по другому ни как)

Comment: Можно и с условием но будет не так читаемо, можно и на js, но визуально можно будет заметить момент оборачивания элементов, потому что они будут перестраиваться

Comment: В таком варианте, у меня совсем перестало выводить цикл.

Comment: В плане не стало выводить? Ошибку высыпает или дивы пустые? Обновил код - добавил true в array_chunk для сохранения ключей

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mom2ey

Comment: locationsHolder это обертка

Comment: обновил ответ. Я специально прикрепил ссылку на доки - array_chunk) она для использования в php. Вам не нужен js вообще для этой задачи